# How to preserve JS object data after the object you set it to changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-scheduler

I have a scheduler with custom events. In the edit event popup, there is a cancel button. The scheduler is from a javascript library, so not of my creation, I only created its custom functionality.

So in the edit popup (which triggers edit event), I set a variable to hold the current state of the event data. Then if I make any changes and press cancel instead of save, the cancel event is triggered. In the cancel event, the 'currentState' event data is now changed to the new state of all the changed data, which I don't want. I need the old data so I can revert it all back, then refresh scheduler.

This is my cancel event:

```
cancel: function(e){
                            console.log('Cancelling', e);

                            var kendoEvent = new kendo.data.SchedulerEvent();
                            var schema = e.sender.dataSource.options.schema.model.fields;
                            console.log(e.sender.dataSource.hasChanges());
                            console.log(currentEventState);
                            $.each(schema, function(index, value){
                                //console.log(value);
                                console.log(index);
                                kendoEvent[index] = e.sender.oldEventData[index]; 
                                if(index == 'ownerId'){
                                    kendoEvent.ownerId = currentEventState.ownerId[0].value;
                                }
                            });

                            console.log(kendoEvent);
                            console.log(getIndexById(kendoEvent.taskId));
                            eventData[getIndexById(kendoEvent.taskId)] = kendoEvent;
                            e.sender.dataSource.read();
                            if(e.event.id != '0'){
                                dontUpdate = 1;
                                //e.sender.dataSource.sync();
                            }
                        },
```

Where e.sender is the scheduler, and e.event is the event data (with any changes that were made). In the edit event the first thing I do is add oldEventData field to e.sender and set it to e.event. But... if changes are made to e.event AFTER e.sender.oldEventData is set, e.sender.oldEventData STILL gets changed to reflect all the changes made...

How might I preserve this old data so I can revert it back? I tried just doing a global variable instead of creating a new field in e.sender, but after setting the global variable to e.event, it still reflected any changes made >:(.

Answer (score 1):

Discovered that cloning the data into the field e.sender.oldEventData prevented it from being tied to e.event. So e.event could change without messing with the old data.

This was achieved with a simple JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(e.event)).

I attempted Object.freeze(e.sender.oldEventData), which kept the old data, but made it completely unable to modify at all, so wasn't the best solution for me.